# Can't pickle error when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Python 3.6.8 on Anaconda 2019.07 and I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool` to run several processes the same time using the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=4)
results = pool.starmap(testMethod, args)
pool.close()
```

`testMethod` only contains integers and strings as arguments. `args` is a list of tuples where each tuple contains the arguments for the `testMethod`.

When I try to run the code I'm getting the following error message: `TypeError: can't pickle module objects`.

Why is this?

Comment: Looks like somehow you passed a module instead of a function I guess, could you provide the full code (all methods, functions and import lines)?

Comment: @Arount The problem was indeed that I passed a module. I fixed it.